# Get SPList Items Column Titles and Column Data including the SPLookupFieldValue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Below source printing only the List Items that are on the first page of the SPList. Not printing the ListItems data in other pages i.e., Page 2, Page 3 etc.

Also it is required to print SPLookupFieldValue, rather than suggesting some links any modifications to the below source that can meet the requirement is greatly appereciated

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://intranet.contoso.com"))
    {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
        // Get data from a list. 
        SPList list = web.Lists["Products"];
        SPView view = list.DefaultView;

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(view);
        // Get a collection of view field names. 
        StringCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();
        // Print data for each item in the view. 
        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
          // Print the value of each view field. 
          foreach (string fieldName in viewFields)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", fieldName, item[fieldName]);
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
        }
      }
    }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Country Column is Lookup, so the data is printed with ID and value. Needs to print only the value.
    Product = Television
    Country  = 2;#uk
    Product = Car
    Country = 1;#india

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get items with list.GetItems()

Second check is the field lookup, get SPFieldLookupValue, then get the value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://intranet.contoso.com"))
    {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // Get data from a list. 
        SPList list = web.Lists["Products"];
        SPView view = list.DefaultView;

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
        // Get a collection of view field names. 
        StringCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection();
        // Print data for each item in the view. 
        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            // Print the value of each view field. 
            foreach (string fieldName in viewFields)
            {
                SPField field = list.Fields.GetField(fieldName);
                if (field.Type == SPFieldType.Lookup)
                {
                    string strValue = item[fieldName].ToString();
                    string value = new SPFieldLookupValue(strValue).LookupValue;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", fieldName, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", fieldName, item[fieldName]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Naim.  one minor correction has made the day!! string strValue = list[fieldName].ToString(); should be          string strValue = item[fieldName].ToString();